# Is there a Salesforce data-loading/ETL tool that uses Bulk API V2.0?

Tags: data-loader, bulk-api, etl, bulk-api-v2

Is there a data-loading/ETL tool that uses Salesforce's Bulk API v2.0?

I see that both Data Loader and dataloader.io, in Bulk mode, still only use Bulk API v1.0.

And please do NOT say "Workbench"--the [various](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/walkthrough_upload_data.htm) [Workbench](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/walkthrough_upload_multipart_data.htm) [walkthroughs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/walkthrough_upsert.htm) in the [Bulk API 2.0 and Bulk API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_quickstart.htm) are mere proofs-of-concept that (1) require annoying amounts of manual fiddling and (2) can't handle large data volumes.

Comment: [Mulesoft + Salesforce connector](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/api-connectors-templates/bulk-api-v2-support-salesforce-connector/). Can be thought of as an ETL tool if you squint hard enough.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement from bulk v2 that you're after?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually built a data importing tool which uses the Bulk API v2 https://dataimporter.io

Let me know if you have any questions.